# Issue with image view orgin in ios

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am doing a module where there is a pin drop functionality. 
The pin[Image view] is dropped on a scroll view which is zoom-able.
When zoomed the the image view moves in accordance with its center orgin.

I would like to make it moved with its bottom point.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale;
{
    zoomLevel=scale;
    for (SSSmartPinView *smartPinView in smartPinViewMutArray) {
        smartPinView.zoomScale = zoomLevel;
        smartPinView.parrentOffset = drawingScrollView.contentOffset;
        smartPinView.center = CGPointMake(([smartPinView.coresmartPin.xpoint floatValue]*zoomLevel),(([smartPinView.coresmartPin.ypoint floatValue]+(zoomLevel))*zoomLevel));



    }


}
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    zoomLevel=scrollView.zoomScale;
    for (SSSmartPinView *smartPinView in smartPinViewMutArray){
        smartPinView.zoomScale = zoomLevel;
        smartPinView.parrentOffset = drawingScrollView.contentOffset;

      smartPinView.center = CGPointMake(([smartPinView.coresmartPin.xpoint floatValue]*zoomLevel),(([smartPinView.coresmartPin.ypoint floatValue]+(zoomLevel))*zoomLevel));


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the *anchor* (center point for rotation / scaling) with

```
smartPinView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
```

See the [anchorPoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/anchorPoint) property

Comment: you dont want to be placing things on a pixel boundary, so use CGRectIntegral on the final frame to avoid blurry images.